# Command button deletes when I run script VBA

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

I have a VBA script which **runs to delete any pictures / screen shots** in Excel in **all worksheets**. However when I press the button, my button is also deleted.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    Sheet.Activate
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        Pic.Delete
    Next Pic
Next Sheet

ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### This may not be exact, but it should get you on the right path

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    Sheet.Activate
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        If Pic <> CommandButton1.Picture Then
            Pic.Delete
        End If
    Next Pic
Next Sheet

ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @ PatD it works if a form control is used as opposed to activeX controls